# WordPress hiding category specific html

Tags: wordpress, categories, woocommerce

I'm looking for a way to hide a "form" drop down menu in WooCommerce but only on a specific category page. We'll call it "marbles", the drop down to select the ordering of items I would like to not appear, but on the category "apples" and other pages I would like for it to remain visible. I've tried using code similar to `#category-id-15 form.woocommerce-ordering {display: none;}` but that didn't seem to do the trick. Can this be done using CSS only or would I need to create an action for it?
Here's the page I'm trying to hide the drop down menu on -
[CATEGORY PAGE](http://kdrosaries.com/product-category/rosary-czech-crystals/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can  hide it using CSS. But Wordpress offers a function `is_category()` to do such operations .

In your  category.php file, try using this:

```
 if (!(is_category('marbles'))){
        include(TEMPLATEPATH.'/part.php'); 
    }
```

where `part.php` is the php code where you have your drop down menu.

I am here to provide with more support.

Comment: Would it be possible to create a custom functions.php file to override the menu from being displayed?
I ask because I'm not sure where the code is being hailed in from.

Comment: I don't think I understand you 100 percent, but just show me your category.php file as an edit, especially the part responsible of displaying the menu. I don't think functions.php is a file to touch. anyway, we will digg together till finding the solution

Comment: just to answer your question, it is not possible to create a second functions.php file. whenever you need to add a function, you can add it to functions.php

Comment: I found the file that's calling the menu "woocommerce/templates/loop/orderby.php"
Can we make it to where the code is something like?
'if (is_category('marbles')){
        hide(TEMPLATEPATH.'/orderby.php'); 
    }'

Comment: I never used woocommerce, but, what you are doing seems to be the good approach. Find in your category.php of your theme, where orderby.php is called, then wrap the code with if (!(is_category( 'marbles'))){include(TEMPLATEPATH.'/orderby.php');}. bett!er use '!' than try to find what is the equivalent of 'hide'. I ve edited